# freeSSHd SCP Linux to Windows Fails with "exec request failed on channel 0"

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp, freesshd

Windows has freeSSHd installed.  Logging in with ssh from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS via SSH using Windows Login credentials works fine.  Logging in with SFTP also works fine.

This test is being run from a virtual machine in VirtualBox to the host running Windows 7 Professional.

Trying various combinations of (port is 2222):

```
scp -v -P 2222 xxxxxx@172.26.170.180:at.exe .
```

fails with

```
Next authentication method: password
xxxxx@172.26.170.180's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 172.26.170.180 ([172.26.170.180]:2222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f at.exe
exec request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624881/freesshd-cannot-be-accessed-by-scp

Comment: I read the suggested comment a while ago but after lots of research it made more sense to me.  Thanks for pointing me back there.  I have finally settled for Cygwin for my SSH / SCP on Windows as my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should open SFTP in freesshd user tab.